# VCL styles missing in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

My list of VCL Styles is empty in Delphi XE3.

[image: Project | Options | Appearance]

I also have Delphi XE7 installed, and the VCL styles are showing fine in here.

I have checked for other solutions, [one of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005327/where-do-vcl-styles-come-from/15010312#15010312) suggests checking the style files exist in the correct paths, which they do. For Delphi XE3, this would be:

C:\Users\Jason\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Styles

There are 27 .vsf files in this directory.

Another [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794973/fix-vcl-styles-directory-in-delphi-xe3) suggested running the redistsetup.bat file which I ran with the "Default" option, but this made no difference.

Does anyone have any other ideas of what I could check, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to relocate the styles to :

> C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Styles

Comment: @J__ Glad to help a fellow J

Comment: On newer versions it's in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\NN.0\Styles\ (replace NN with version number: 17 = Delphi 10 Seattle, 18 = Delphi 10.1 Berlin, 19 - Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, 20 = Delphi 10.3 Rio, 21 = Delphi 10.4 Sydney, 22 = Delphi 11 Alexandria)